# Merge 2 pdf files in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, cgpdf

I am trying to merge   two PDF files in iOS. I am merging page-by-page. It takes a lot of time in case of very big files. Is there any way, we can just merge the two files, instead of page-by-page ?

I can post my code , if you want.

My code is similat to the one [Here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610521/merging-pdf-files-in-cocoa)

Comment: u can follow the post i have given if u know the path of the pdf files

Answer (score 14):

Try this code..It adds up 1st pdf file then at the of that it,it adds 2nd pdf file to make single pdf.

```
NSString *cacheDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

// File paths
NSString *pdfPath1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pdf1" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSString *pdfPath2 = [cacheDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp.pdf"];
NSString *pdfPathOutput = [cacheDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"out.pdf"];

// File URLs - bridge casting for ARC
CFURLRef pdfURL1 = (__bridge_retained CFURLRef)[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:(NSString *)pdfPath1];//(CFURLRef) NSURL
CFURLRef pdfURL2 = (__bridge_retained CFURLRef)[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:(NSString *)pdfPath2];//(CFURLRef)
CFURLRef pdfURLOutput =(__bridge_retained CFURLRef) [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:(NSString *)pdfPathOutput];//(CFURLRef)

// File references
CGPDFDocumentRef pdfRef1 = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef) pdfURL1);
CGPDFDocumentRef pdfRef2 = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef) pdfURL2);

// Number of pages
NSInteger numberOfPages1 = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdfRef1);
NSInteger numberOfPages2 = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdfRef2);

// Create the output context
CGContextRef writeContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL(pdfURLOutput, NULL, NULL);

// Loop variables
CGPDFPageRef page;
CGRect mediaBox;

// Read the first PDF and generate the output pages
NSLog(@"GENERATING PAGES FROM PDF 1 (%i)...", numberOfPages1);
for (int i=1; i<=numberOfPages1; i++) {
    page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdfRef1, i);
    mediaBox = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox);
    CGContextBeginPage(writeContext, &mediaBox);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(writeContext, page);
    CGContextEndPage(writeContext);
}

// Read the second PDF and generate the output pages
NSLog(@"GENERATING PAGES FROM PDF 2 (%i)...", numberOfPages2);
for (int i=1; i<=numberOfPages2; i++) {
    page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdfRef2, i);
    mediaBox = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox);
    CGContextBeginPage(writeContext, &mediaBox);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(writeContext, page);
    CGContextEndPage(writeContext);      
}
NSLog(@"DONE!");

// Finalize the output file
CGPDFContextClose(writeContext);

// Release from memory
CFRelease(pdfURL1);
CFRelease(pdfURL2);
CFRelease(pdfURLOutput);
CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdfRef1);
CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdfRef2);
CGContextRelease(writeContext);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Shame it was never marked as correct answer.

Comment: Not marked as answer. @Nathan because you never get reward for copy past
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448446/add-pdf-page-to-an-existing-pdf-objective-c

Comment: I modified this code to work with NSData instead of working with files. Works like a charm

Answer (score 6):

Use this method for any number of pdfs this may help u

```
+ (NSString *)joinPDF:(NSArray *)listOfPath{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *layOutPath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/mergepdf/pdf",[paths objectAtIndex:0]];
    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:layOutPath]){
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:layOutPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];        
    } 
    // File paths
    NSString *fileName = @"ALL.pdf";
    NSString *pdfPathOutput = [layOutPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    CFURLRef pdfURLOutput = (__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPathOutput];
    NSInteger numberOfPages = 0;
    // Create the output context
    CGContextRef writeContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL(pdfURLOutput, NULL, NULL);

    for (NSString *source in listOfPath) {
//        CFURLRef pdfURL = (__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:source];

       CFURLRef pdfURL =  CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation(NULL, [source UTF8String],[source length], NO);

        //file ref
        CGPDFDocumentRef pdfRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(pdfURL);
        numberOfPages = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdfRef);

        // Loop variables
        CGPDFPageRef page;
        CGRect mediaBox;

        // Read the first PDF and generate the output pages
        DLog(@"GENERATING PAGES FROM PDF 1 (%@)...", source);
        for (int i=1; i<=numberOfPages; i++) {
            page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdfRef, i);
            mediaBox = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox);
            CGContextBeginPage(writeContext, &mediaBox);
            CGContextDrawPDFPage(writeContext, page);
            CGContextEndPage(writeContext);
        }

        CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdfRef);
        CFRelease(pdfURL);
    }
  // CFRelease(pdfURLOutput);
//    
//    // Finalize the output file
   CGPDFContextClose(writeContext);
    CGContextRelease(writeContext);

    return pdfPathOutput;
}
```