# Add a signature image to existing pdf in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, webview

I am trying to open pdf in web view and add signature on it and save again with signature.
From [this tutorial I am able to add image by creating new PDF](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6818/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2)

but I want to add image on existing PDF.Is there any way to do this.Please help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: Try with this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331791/edit-pdf-in-iphone-application

Comment: You cannot modify an existing PDF in iOS. All you can do is create a new one, draw the old one into the new one and add the signature image.

Comment: I have done this using quartz. Please check my response : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154614/add-a-signature-image-to-a-pdf-without-showing-the-pdf-data-to-user-in-ios